# How to open task scheduler ?

Tags: java

The path to task scheduler is

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\System Tools
```

I tried to open it

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"+\"%ProgramData%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Accessories\\System Tools\\Task Scheduler.exe\");
```

However, the above does not compile . How can I improve my code ?

Comment: if you want the platform-independent task scheduler, use http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: Look at any syntax highlighting, and the error message the compiler's giving you. That string isn't terminated (you have a closing quote for the internal quoted path for `cmd`, but not one for the Java string literal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only wanting the compiler error fixed, you need to properly escape the path like below.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"" + "%ProgramData%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Accessories\\System Tools\\Task Scheduler.exe\"");
   }
```

If you need quotes in the string, you escape with a `\`.

If you need to just open the task scheduler on Windows, try the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + "%windir%\\system32\\taskschd.msc /s");
```

Comment: Is there not an escaped quote missing in your last string, i. e. `..."%windir%\\system32\\taskschd.msc\" /s");`?

Comment: @FrankPl good point.  I guess it doesn't matter since there are no spaces in the path.  I have corrected.